# How to say  "pull the plug" in German?

Tags: idiom, proverb

A literal, physical translation of "we pulled the plug" is "Wir zogen den Stecker."

But sometimes, this expression is used in a figurative sense

> We "pulled the plug" on the project.

Is there a German idiom used this kind of context? Or is the literal translate still the best one?

Comment: The literal translation does not work at all, LEO proposes "den Hahn zudrehen", but this only works in some contexts.

Comment: @Phira means specifically stopping the money supply (Geld-Hahn) for a project. Would imho fit fine (put it as answer), if you stop the project that way and because of that reason.

Comment: I removed my answer because of critisism regarding quoting other answers and comments in the hope that we will see more good answers  here. Only then the *"best"* answer may evolve by voting.

Comment: See also: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/292/23

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of suddenly aborting a project, [Linguee confirms my guess](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=reissleine%20ziehen) that

> die Reißleine ziehen (german well-known metaphor - "pull the rip cord")

would be appropriate german idiom. I think you should adapt this on in English,  as "pull the plug" you would also say when having a bluescreen/freeze on an electrical device, while "pulling the plug on a project" probably means more that there are constructional flaws, planning errors... shit happened. If you simply mean "canceling the project" (for whatever reason), imho a metaphor is not really necessary/appropriate.

Comment: I do agree with @Gigili that vulgar slang expressions should be avoided when they are not the topic.

Answer (score 3):

> den Stecker ziehen

Usage:

Applicable for all electrical devices using a power cord or are related to them.

When something is no longer supported or continued - it emphasizes an abrupt ending.

When someone is in a coma and there is no hope and the doctors decide to end that its really like pulling the plug.

I bit disagree with "die Reißleine ziehen", because it means stopping a thing before it gets worse anyway may apply to some situations.

> die Reißleine ziehen

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation

> den Stecker ziehen

in a figurative sense is also quite common in German.

Examples of recent usage (found through [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22den%20Stecker%20ziehen%22)):

> Rechtsstreit geht weiter: Samsung will Apple den Stecker ziehen
>   *TAZ, September 2011*

or

> "Braunkohle den Stecker ziehen"
>   *Motto von Braunkohlegegner-Aktionsgruppen*

Comment: *"Plug"* may also be a "*Stöpsel*" ;)

Comment: aktionistisches Marketing/Übertreibung, Apple wird eine Multimilliarden-Moloch wie Samsung garantiert nicht den Stecker ziehen ;) Eher friert die Hölle zu, da wäre wohl eher "bremsen" angebracht. Aber in der Werbung zu arbeiten muss doll sein, hat man alle Freiheiten wo gibt ;)

Comment: The literal translation is IMO *not* very common, and most of the google hits refer to cases, where electricity/data is the topic and the rhetorical figure is somehow related to the topic. Even in these cases I find this expression a little bit awkward.

Comment: The literal translation seems to me to be an americanism.

Answer (score 2):

I am not at all a native speaker of German, but as an advanced learner who's been living in Germany for about 10 years now I would translate

> We pulled the plug on the project.

using the following idiom:

> Wir haben das Projekt aufs Eis gelegt.

This does not reflect 100% the original meaning, but this is a common way to say that the project has been stopped or suspended.

Comment: It's totally not what "pull the plug" means.  Pulling the plug means it's dead.  And you stopped it abruptly, without much warning. "Auf Eis legen" means to suspend it.